# Mysql like clause throwing syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I am generating the below query as part of our system:

```
SELECT * FROM (`videos`) WHERE (
    `videos`.`title` LIKE "%apple%" 
  OR WHERE 
    `videos`.`byline` LIKE "%apple%" 
  OR WHERE `videos`.`description` LIKE "%apple%"
);
```

However, this is throwing a syntax error.

So, what's up?

Note that I need the brackets as those three `where`'s are linked, often followed by separate `AND WHERE`'s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sql statements use single quotes around literal values.  Also only one where clause is needed in this case.  Simply use one where clause and then use `or` to connect the predicates.  The script also has some parenthesis that are not required.

The final result looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE
    `videos`.`title` LIKE '%apple%' OR 
    `videos`.`byline` LIKE '%apple%' OR 
    `videos`.`description` LIKE '%apple%';
```

Answer (score 0):

is OR WHERE valid SQL?
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`videos`) WHERE (
    `videos`.`title` LIKE "%apple%" 
  OR  
    `videos`.`byline` LIKE "%apple%" 
  OR `videos`.`description` LIKE "%apple%"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "**OR WHERE**" with "**WHERE**" and replace **double quote** with **single quote** " ---> '